# I used where_in to retrieve records from database by passing array , but its not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below function is used to get mail id of respected users

```
function getMomMailId($data){
    $this->db->select('email');
    $this->db->from('tbl_users');
    //I used where_in, and compared the array of user ids with ids in another table 
    $this->db->where_in('userId',$data['toid']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result_array();
    return($result);
}
```

For two number of records, it gives me all email ids from the database table.and there are two records in the array. It should only two email ids.

Comment: Please post your `$data` array in your question.

Comment: data array is like Array ( [0] => Array ( [toid] => 34 ) [1] => Array ( [toid] => 37 ) )

Comment: please correct your data array into single array.

Comment: i get that array by using $query->result_array();            If you have  any suggestion to correct it please tell me.

Comment: Please correct your post `$data` like `$toid= array('10', '12')` than add condition on your active query. `$this->db->where_in('userId',$toid);`

Comment: I corrected my $data but still its not working properly. It gives me all email ids in output

Comment: Okay you can post your full stuff with `$data` array values and other codeigniter active query.